# How to load a component in a Service (Angular 2+)?

Tags: angular

I want to load a `ng-template` in a service, in order to create a dialog box.

Is there a way to achieve this?

example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "temp",
  template: ` <ng-template #dialogTemplate>
    <p>{{ line1 }}</p>
    <p>{{ line2 }}</p>
  </ng-template>`,
})
class DialogTemplateComponent {
  @ViewChild("dialogTemplate")
  public teplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() {}

  public line1: string = "test";
  public line2: string = "test2";
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class ActionDialogBoxService {
  /// let templateRef = DialogTemplateComponent.templateRef
  /// render the templateRef in a dialogbox
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass that template to the service as a function argument. The exact same thing is done in `MatDialog`

```js
@ViewChild("dialogTemplate")
public teplateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
private dialoService:ActionDialogBoxService;
    
dialogService.openDiaog(this.templateRef,....);
```

You can use it as implementation reference https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: Ok i understood. But i just want to call my service e.g. by `service.open()` and the service itself should create a template by its own and render it. i just tried to create the component with the templateRef locally (without mentioned in `@NgModule`), but it failed.
is there a way to "create" a `templateRef` in the service programmatically?

Comment: You can always try to create component (using ComponentFactory) and attach it to the DOM from service - but you yours example you want to pass template from the template definition. https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader